# PFTwitter Utils for Swift

Tags: swift, twitter, parse-platform

racking my brain on this one but I am unable to get the PFTwitterUtils to work within swift.

I have imported all the relevant files from Parse (including PFTwitter Utils)

but it just won't recognise it for me to create an instance.

Does anyone know why this is happening? this is all I have so far

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Foundation




class ViewController: UIViewController {



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

    @IBAction func loginWithTwitter(sender: AnyObject) {



       PFTwitterUtils







    }


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `import ParseTwitterUtils` on the top of your ViewController